# How do i map network drive with User Credentials

Tags: networking, windows-services

I would like to know how do i map a network drive with user Credentials and is it
possible to map network drive with local system account ??

Comment: This question is not programming related.

Comment: yaa true..its not programming related

Answer (score 1):

Use the following script in bat:

```
net use z: \\remotebox\sharedFolder /USER:user1 password
```